# How can I add commas for every 3 digits in UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to display something like 1,000,000.99 instead of 1000000.99 on my textfield as the user type in their number in the textfield. I have looked at other questions and none really work for my needs & code. I have the following right now. I am trying to add the new code on top of what I currently have.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    int countDots = (int)[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:(@".")].count-1;
    if (countDots > 0 && [string  isEqual: @"."]) {
        return NO;
    } else if ([textField.text length]>12 && [string length] > range.length) {
                   return NO;
    } else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Right now, my conditions check for 'only 1 decimal' and maximum '12 digits'. I want to be able to add commas

Comment: Use a `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: I did but it just keeps replacing the text values with zeros

Comment: @EricChuang if you have tried something then it should be in the question. `NSNumberFormatter` is the correct way to do this. It would be better to show your `NSNumberFormatter` code so that we can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // important line!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4000000]];
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

The `NSNumberFormatter` class is designed for exactly this.

You should be able to do this...

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter new];
nf.perMillSymbol = @",";
```

Then when you want your string you can do...

```
textfield.text = [nf stringFromNumber:@1000000000000.95];
```

Comment: should I implement this in shouldChangeCharacterInRange?

Comment: I would suggest only creating the number formatter once. But yes, you can use it in that delegate method.